# Using Kotlin singleton from Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, singleton

I've read up on this and everything I'm seeing says I should be able to do this so there must be some little thing I'm missing.  I've converted a Java class to Kotlin:

```
object OrderTitle {
  @JvmOverloads
    fun generateMessage(context: Activity, otherParameter: AType? = null): AnotherType {
        // Do some things
   }
}
```

And I call it from Java:

```
message = OrderTitle.generateMessage(activity, property);
```

and get this error:

```
error: non-static method generateMessage(Activity,Property) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: try this instead `OrderTitle.INSTANCE. generateMessage()`

Comment: If its a singleton, you'd call it on an instance of OrderTitle, not the class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Annotate your function with `@JvmStatic` so a real static java function is generated when compiling.

Comment: Whether the object is companion or not doesn't make a difference: "Kotlin can also generate static methods for functions defined in named objects or companion objects if you annotate those functions as @JvmStatic."

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
object OrderTitle {
    @JvmStatic
    fun generateMessage(context: Activity, otherParameter: AType? = null): AnotherType {
        // Do some things
   }
}
```

and then you can call it from Java:

```
OrderTitle.generateMessage(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to do this is with top level functions,

```
@file:JvmName("ClassNameHere")
fun generateMessage(context: Activity, otherParameter: AType? = null): AnotherType {
    // Do some things
}
```

Then from java just use it as

```
ClassNameHere.generateMessage()
```